# Using Mimicry on an invalid target

Tags: evolution

I have some questions about which of these are legal plays when attacking a creature that has the mimicry attribute.

> Setup: I have a creature that only has mimicry on it. It is attacked by another player who has a creature that only has carnivore on it.

Let's say I have:

1. A creature that only has the swimming attribute.
2. A creature that only has the burrowing attribute, and is FED.
3. A creature that only has the high weight attribute.
4. A creature that is protected by its symbiont.
5. A creature that only has the camouflage attribute.
6. A creature that only has the hibernation ability attribute, and is using it.

Are these legal plays to force a player to attack an invalid target?

I understand the camouflage one possibly being OK, since we thought about how chameleons aren't always camouflaged, but what about animals that violate the theme more expressely, like swimming?

I heard arguments while playing that playing mimicry to force a player to attack a high body weight creature was ok because "animals puff up all the time to look bigger than they are", and hence, avoid getting eaten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're referring to the original version of Evolution. (I'm pretty sure the North Star Games version doesn't have mimicry). The new target must be eligible for attack by carnivore. [You can not force it to attack an invalid target.](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1257724/question-about-mimicry)